# SQL Cluster, AlwaysOn AG, or Something Else?

Tags: sql-server, clustering, availability-groups, high-availability

I really needs some help with Setting up SQL servers.  We are re-configuring our network and have no clue how to resolve our SQL issue.  My Network Admin. wants an "Active/Active" with shared storage (SAN) solution.  The reason for this is load balancing, redundancy, and auto-fail over.  I do not believe this can be done or should be done.  Please help me figure this out.  I have listed some info. below on our setup.  Thank you

1. We will most likely use three servers, possible using VMs
2. We have a SAN with 1GB networking
3. Solution needs to have auto-fail over and the secondary node's database needs to be synchronous
4. If possible with a solution to have mixed hardware (Intel, AMD)
5. All servers and equipment located in one location
6. We will be using either SQL Server 2012 R2 or 2014

Comment: In addition to many of the valid points below, whether you use Intel or AMD doesn't really affect anything (though I would probably try to stick with Intel if I were you), and there is no such thing as "SQL Server 2012 R2."

Comment: @Lebron:You are correct about load balancing multi instance cluster or any cluster does not provides load balancing as such LB is application feature.

Answer (score 4):

> My Network Admin. wants an "Active/Active" with shared storage

There is no such thing as an "active/active" instance.  Only one node of the cluster can be hosting the SQL instance for a failover cluster instance.  If by "active/active" you mean having two different SQL Server failover cluster instances, that is possible.

Why shared storage?  That's an odd "requirement", and usually comes as a need from a requirement, not typically a requirement itself.  The failover cluster instance would exercise shared storage, but different replicas in an availability group would have their own storage.

> load balancing

There is no load balancing with a failover cluster instance.  For an availability group, you can offload certain operations to secondary replicas (reporting/readonly workloads, backups, etc.), but there is no fully capable (data modifying) load that can be offloaded to a secondary.

> redundancy

This can be achieved with either a failover cluster instance and/or an availability group.

> auto-fail over

This can be achieved with either a failover cluster instance or an availability group.

One of the main questions you need to ask yourself is what level of high availability are you looking for?  A failover cluster instance will give you HA for the whole instance, whereas an availability group will give you high availability of a grouping of databases as a unit of failover.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  Here is the answer to the SAN question.  A third party group helped us purchase some equipment and was suppose to help with our Windows Clustering/SQL setup.  I believe my Network Admin thinks that the SAN needs/has to be used.  He truly thinks their is an "Active/Active" solution.  I have been researching this for about 3 weeks. We are suppose to meet Friday or beginning of next week.  We are a EMR/WebPAP software company, so being up, redundant, and efficient is very important.  To clarify we are using 2012 server and there is no dedicated positions.

Comment: A SAN does not need to be used with a Windows Cluster and an availability group.  You will need shared storage if you go with a failover cluster instance (SQL).

Comment: Agreed.  He has a Window Failover Cluster that is connection to the SAN.  I believe he was thinking of treating the SQL setup the same, but I realize from research it isn't the same or shouldn't be the same.  I believe for what he wants the AlwaysOn Availability Groups is the way to go.  We can attach one of the secondary SQL servers to the SAN for backup purposes.